# Maven plugin dependency in the same project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Here is a sample repository for this case: https://github.com/xShadov/maven-plugin-dependency-sample

When maven plugin uses a plugin dependency, and that dependency comes from the same project, maven cannot do it - it fails immediately. That is not the case with normal dependencies, only plugin dependencies.

I try to do it with `spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin`, but the case is generic, it happens with every plugin. Spring cloud contract in their samples have exactly the same case ([beer-common-dependency](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/17ee4fcae845e9c4e6b290beaf4b9d7e5d863448/producer_java/pom.xml#L122)), but looking at their `README`, they have the same problem (`You can run Maven from the root folder once the "common" module has been installed.`).

Is there a way to solve it? I couldn't find one, and neither could guys from spring cloud contract, so probably not, but I want to be sure. Is it a bug or intended maven behavior?

This problem is serious for me, it's not possible to build a project with a single command, and complicates things even further on CI, because of version mismatch.

Comment: So are you talking about `mvn clean install`, or something like `mvn clean package`?

Comment: `mvn clean install`

Comment: What do you mean exactly by plugin dependency? A dependency of the plugin, or a dependency you add to the plugin definition in your POM? Is this purely a problem of build order?

Comment: Have a look at the repo I linked, it demonstrates this problem exactly. Problem is that dependency of a plugin comes from the same project, and maven immediately throws error instead building. This is not a build order problem.

Comment: I just mean that if `plugin-dependency-module` is build before `business-module`, it does not matter any more. Then, `plugin-dependency-module` is in the local repository and therefore can be read like any other dependency. I do I misunderstand something?

Comment: That's exactly how it works for later builds, but on the first build `plugin-dependency-module` is not in a local repository. If you download that sample repo, run `mvn clean install` in root folder - it will fail. If you run `mvn clean install` on `plugin-dependency-module` alone, it will build, then run it in root folder and it will work - but it's 2 separate maven builds, not one.

Comment: The thing I find very confusing. If you run `mvn clean install` in the root folder, and the order is correct, meaning `plugin-dependency-module` is build before `business-module`, then `plugin-dependency-module` will be installed in the local repository, and THEN `business-module` is build. So I cannot really wrap my head around why it should make a difference if you build `plugin-dependency-module` separately.

Comment: Because maven does some starting validation before building anything, and that validation fails immediately, because maven cannot find `plugin-dependency-module` in repository. So nothing is built.